# C++ OpenCV cv::inRange function not working in a scope while working in another

Tags: c++, opencv

So i have this function called `preprocess()` where I call `cv::cvtColor`, `cv::GaussianBlur` and `cv::inRange`. The first two work perfectly, but for some reason the `cv::inRange` function doesn't. However, calling it in the scope where i call the `preprocess()` function makes it work. Why is this happening and how can I solve it? This is the code for the `preprocess` function :

```
int preprocess(cv::Mat target, int flag, int debug)
{
    if (!debug) 
    {
        if (flag ==    BLUR) cv::GaussianBlur(target, target, cv::Size(3, 3), 3, 0);
        if (flag ==  TO_HSV) cv::cvtColor(target, target, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);
        if (flag == ISOLATE) cv::inRange(target, LOWER_LIMIT, UPPER_LIMIT, target);

        return OK;
    }

    // if debugging is enable, convert the image based on the flag then outputs it
    preprocess(target, flag, 0);
    OUTPUT = target;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));

    return OK;
}
```

This is the snippet that causes problems:

```
// process the image based on the flag 
    if (!preprocess(map, BLUR,    debug)) std::cout << "error while processing image: blur"    << std::endl;
    if (!preprocess(map, TO_HSV,  debug)) std::cout << "error while processing image: to_hsv"  << std::endl;
    if (!preprocess(map, ISOLATE, debug)) std::cout << "error while processing image: isolate" << std::endl; //this doesn't

    cv::inRange(map, LOWER_LIMIT, UPPER_LIMIT, map); // this works
    OUTPUT = map;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
```

The `debug` parameter simply updates my global `OUTPUT` object so I can display step by step what happens to my image and the flags are macros defined to decide what I want to do inside the `preprocess()` function. `map` and `target` are the same `cv::Mat` object

Comment: Have you try pass the image by reference?

Comment: @Mike I haven't tried it since I know that cv::Mat objects are using smart pointers internally. Besides, as mentioned before, the first two operations on the target image work, I think it has to do something with the format of the image changing from CV_UC3 to CV_8UC1. I will try using references tho, I'll let you know if it works!